# Does white chocolate HAVE to have milk in it?

Tags: chocolate, vegan

I've looked through the ingredient labels of cheap candy bars, and quality baking white chocolate chips alike, and have been unable to find any milk-less white chocolate, they all contain either milk fat, skim milk, or dry milk.

Has anyone seen vegan white chocolate before, or is it even possible to make?

Comment: Vegan white chocolate does exist; google "vegan white chocolate" and you will find options.  I cannot vouch for the flavor.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

White chocolate [by regulation](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?fr=163.124) is at least 3.5% milk fat and 14% milk solids. As far as I know, the EU uses the same definition as the FDA (US).

So, nothing vegan can legally be sold as "white chocolate".

That said, there are a great many non-dairy white chocolate *substitutes*, usually made with any combination of soy milk, maltodextrin, vanilla, and saturated/hydrogenated fat (palm oil, shortening, etc.), among other ingredients/additives of course.

They don't taste the same as real white chocolate, but then again, white chocolate isn't real chocolate to begin with, so it can't hurt to experiment with some of the products out there - which can be easily sourced with a Google search, as one of the comments indicates.

Comment: Nice catch, I did not realize we had standards of identity white chocolate.

Comment: I didn't know there were regulations for chocolate - thanks for the prompt answer!

Comment: .....Can I just point out that white "chocolate" is real chocolate as long as it contains at least 20% cocoa butter? White "baking chips" and such like is the fake stuff you have to look out for. The real stuff can be hard to find, and the fake stuff is often deceptively labelled-- you have to check the ingredients list to make sure you're getting real chocolate instead of sweetened condensed milk in disguise. (I'm in the US too, btw.)

Answer (score 5):

You can make your own vegan white chocolate by using raw cacao butter + some vegan powdered sugar + a little vanilla + some coconut oil (so it doesn't solidify at too low a temperature).

1. Melt 1/2 cup raw cocoa butter in the microwave - be gentle - cycle on/off 20 second increments.
2. in a stand mixer, blend 1 cup Vegan powdered sugar and 1 tsp Vanilla (also 1/4 tsp salt if desired)
3. Add 1 TBSP melted coconut oil
4. Mix until blended together.
5. pour in molds to cool, or alternately pour on a piece of parchment paper and let cool, then break into pieces.

Comment: Just a warning to be REALLY careful with the coconut oil-- it actually interferes with the cocoa butter's ability to crystallize at all. You can read all about it at chocolate alchemy if you're interested. (http://chocolatealchemy.com/blog/2018/3/9/ask-the-alchemist-242) That said, there are plenty of additives that can be used to help you soften or harden your final (hopefully tempered) chocolate. If you want to soften it, I would actually recommend a vegetable shortening ( like Crisco, if that's cool) as something basically flavorless that won't potentially wreck that pricey cocoa butter.

Answer (score 3):

White chocolate in it's purest form is manufactured from cocoa butter. Min. content must be 26% cocoa butter fat, milk fat and milk solids, vanilla & lecithin emulsifiers.  White confectionery on the other hand is vegetable fat substituted for the cocoa butter which is misleadingly labeled "chocolate". So I guess as long as the white chocolate is made from cocoa butter it can also be made from other non dairy ingredients perhaps. Although I haven't personally seen, tried or heard of any. But to label it chocolate it HAS to have the cocoa butter as it's melting property and not vegetable fat.

Answer (score 0):

[This product](http://www.bakerschoiceny.com/itempage-wch%2018_068-217-208-215.html) has no dairy in it.

It has no chocolate either LOL. It's from Israel, I guess the rules are different there.

Anyway, I've tasted it, and it does taste like white chocolate.

Ingredients:

- Sugar
- Soybean Oil
- Lecithin
- Vanillin